# Selection a bool through randomizer

Tags: objective-c, random, boolean

I have a total of 6 booleans and the only thing separating them is a number. They're named checker0 though 5.

So checker0, checker1, checker2, checker3, checker4 and checker5.

All of these grants or denies access to certain parts of the app wether the bool is true or false.

I then have a randomiser using:

```
randomQuestionNumber = arc4random_uniform(5);
```

So say we get number 3, checker3 = true;

But my question now is would it be possible to set this one to true without having to go thru if statements.

My idea was to implement the way you print a int to say the NSLog using the %d.

```
NSLog(@"The number is: %d", randomQuestionNumber);
```

So something like:

```
checker%d, randomQuestionNumber = true.
```

Would something like that be possible? So i won't have to do like this:

```
if (randomQuestionNumber == 0) {
    checker0 = true;
}

else if (randomQuestionNumber == 1)
{
    checker1 = true;
}
```

Thanks you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you find yourself in a situation when you name three or more variables `checkerN` you know with a high degree of probability that you've missed a place in code where you should have declared an array. This becomes especially apparent when you need to choose one of `N` based on an integer index.

The best solution would be to change the declaration to `checker[6]`, and using an index instead of changing the name. If this is not possible for some reason, you could still make an array of pointers, and use it to make modifications to your values, like this:

```
BOOL *ptrChecker[] = {&checker0, &checker1, &checker2, ...};
...
*ptrChecker[randomQuestionNumber] = true;
```